# how can I use alternative font format in localFont in next js

Tags: next.js, fonts

I want to use alternative font format in localFont in my next js app.
I mean like what we do in @font-face in css that if browser doesn't support first one goes to next one.
There is no example for this case In next js document and I don't know how can I  do it.
the example of using local font in next js document :

```
const roboto = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: './Roboto-Regular.woff2',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: './Roboto-Italic.woff2',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'italic',
    },
    {
      path: './Roboto-Bold.woff2',
      weight: '700',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: './Roboto-BoldItalic.woff2',
      weight: '700',
      style: 'italic',
    },
  ],
})
```